# How to efficiently calculate the angle between two points?

Tags: c++, math, optimization, game-physics

I am trying to optimize the simulation function in my experiment so I can have more artificial brain-controlled agents running at a time. I profiled my code and found out that the big bottleneck in my code right now is computing the relative angle from every agent to every agent, which is O(n<sup>2</sup>), minus some small optimizations I have done. Here is the current code snippet I have for computing the angle:

```
[C++]
double calcAngle(double fromX, double fromY, double fromAngle, double toX, double toY)
{
    double d = 0.0;
    double Ux = 0.0, Uy = 0.0, Vx = 0.0, Vy = 0.0;

    d = sqrt( calcDistanceSquared(fromX, fromY, toX, toY) );

    Ux = (toX - fromX) / d;

    Uy = (toY - fromY) / d;

    Vx = cos(fromAngle * (cPI / 180.0));
    Vy = sin(fromAngle * (cPI / 180.0));

    return atan2(((Ux * Vy) - (Uy * Vx)), ((Ux * Vx) + (Uy * Vy))) * 180.0 / cPI;
}
```

I have two 2D points (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) and (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>) and the facing of the "from" point (x<sub>a</sub>). I want to compute the angle that agent x needs to turn (relative to its current facing) to face agent y.

According to the profiler, the most expensive part is the **atan2**. I have Googled for hours and the above solution is the best solution I could find. Does anyone know of a more efficient way to compute the angle between two points? I am willing to sacrifice a little accuracy (+/- 1-2 degrees) for speed, if that affects anything.

Comment: No, sorry. Floating-point nonlinear math is expensive.

Comment: "the big bottleneck in my code right now is computing the relative angle from every agent to every agent" Have you considered... not doing that? First, vector math usually doesn't need *angles*; it just uses vectors. What functions are you using where you need an angle specifically? Second, why do you need to compute this for every pair of agents? Don't you only need to compute it for those who are close to one another? There are many techniques for dealing with grouping nearby entities.

Comment: How About lookup tables for sin andere cos? Did you  consider??

Comment: **@Nicol:** I am simulating a 180 degree frontal retina for every agent, so I need the angle so I know which portion of the retina to mark as "having another agent in it." I already precompute the distance and filter out agents that are outside of the agent's possible vision distance. I have also thought about somehow figuring out if agent y is in front of agent x before deciding to compute the relative angle, but I have found that to be a difficult problem without incurring similar costs of just computing the angle directly.

Comment: @Matthias: I doubt that will be faster (assuming we're talking about a modern desktop/server platform here).

Comment: **@Matthias**: The bottleneck in the code here is the atan2 (and the sqrt once the atan2 is removed), not really the sin/cos.

Comment: It might be better to try and optimize the O(n^2), in my mind this means that each agent has to interact with every other agent in the scene. Have you considered using a hierarchical state machine to try and reduce the amount of interaction between agents ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, there are probably high-level approaches to reduce your computational load.

But to the question in hand, you can just use the [dot-product relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_interpretation):

```
theta = acos ( a . b / ||a|| ||b|| )
```

where `a` and `b` are your vectors, `.` denotes "dot product" and `|| ||` denotes "vector magnitude".

Essentially, this will replace your {`sqrt`, `cos`, `sin`, `atan2`} with {`sqrt`, `acos`}.

I would also suggest sticking to radians for all internal calculations, only converting to and from degrees for human-readable I/O.

Comment: Is there a stable C++ library out there that automatically handles this kind of game logic, a la XNA Game Studio's library for C#?

Comment: @RandyOlson: That's out of my area of expertise, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why do you need a library if you know how to calculate a dot product and a magnitude?  It's hardly worthy of a library.

Comment: There's much more to game mechanics than just the dot product and magnitude of a vector.

Comment: You don't need `sqrt` I think:  (a . b / ||a|| ||b||)² = cosθ² =(1+cos2θ)/2

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, it turns out that this isn't the way to compute the angle that agent 'from' [at point (x1,y1) with facing a1]  needs to turn to face agent 'to' [at point (x2,y2)]. This is computing the angle between agent 'from' and agent 'to's facings. The angle I need to compute is not affected by agent 'to's facing.

Comment: @RandyOlson: Apparently I misinterpreted your question.  If there are two points and a "current" angle, then this is trivial.  Your code is already almost there; but I can't see the need for the `sin` and `cos`.  Just compute the angle from P1 to P2 with atan2, and then subtract the "current" angle.  That's the change in angle required.

Comment: @RandyOlson: And to clarify, no, there's really no sensible way to avoid the `atan2` in that case.  You could pull tricks with lookup-tables and polynomial approximations and so on, but it's almost guaranteed that they'll be slower (assuming you're working on a modern server/desktop platform).

Answer (score 1):

Your comment tells a lot: "I am simulating a 180 degree frontal retina for every agent, so I need the angle". No, you don't. You just need to know whether the angle between the position vector and vision vector is more or less than 90 degrees.

That's *very* easy: the dot product `A·B` is >0 if the angle between A and B is less than 90 degrees; 0 if the angle is precisely 90 degrees, and <0 if the angle is more than 90 degrees. Calculating this takes 3 multiplications and 2 additions.

Comment: I eventually need the precise(ish) angle to know which portion of the retina to mark as "having an agent in it," but this is a great idea for further cutting down on the number of times that this function is called. What about if I had a 90-degree frontal retina? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, see Oli's answer (and my comment there) - you need a single `acos` and the rest is just `+-*/`

Comment: Also, you probably don't **need** the angle. it's often easier to use the relative vector projected on the retina plane. Formula: `V_projected = V - Normal*(V·Normal)` (The normal is the unit vector perpendicular to the plane).

Answer (score 0):

i think it's more a mathematical problem:

try

abs(arctan((y1-yfrom)/(x1-xfrom)) - arctan(1/((y2-yfrom2)/(x2-xfrom2))))

Comment: note that the result will be in radians and you have to divide it by pi and multiply it by 180 to get degrees

Comment: isn't fromAngle an angle whereas x1, x2, y1,y2 are coordinates? not sure what you subtract here.

Comment: xfrom and yfrom are both coordinates from where the line starts ... xfrom would be equivalent to his "xa": "facing of the "from" point (xa)"

Answer (score 0):

Use the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of these two vectors and at worst you need to do an inverse cosine instead:

A = Facing direction. B = Direction of Agent Y from Agent X

Calculating the dot is simple multiplication and addition. From that you have the cosine of the angle.

Answer (score 0):

For starters,  you should realize that there are a couple of simplifications that can reduce the calculations a bit:

1. You need not calculate the angle from an agent to itself,
2. If you have the angle from agent i to agent j, you already know something about the angle from agent j back to agent i.

I have to ask: what does "agent i turn to face agent j" mean?  If the two surfaces are looking right at each other, do you have to do a calculation?  What tolerance do you have on "looking right at each other"?

It'd be easier to recommend what to do if you'd stop focusing on the mathematics and describe the problem more fully.

Comment: Already doing 1, of course. :-) Unfortunately 2 doesn't eliminate the atan2, since the atan2 is done relative to the facing of the "from" agent.

Comment: I am simulating a 180 degree frontal retina for every agent, so I need the angle so I know which portion of the retina to mark as "having another agent in it." I already precompute the distance and filter out agents that are outside of the agent's possible vision distance. I have also thought about somehow figuring out if agent y is in front of agent x before deciding to compute the relative angle, but I have found that to be a difficult problem without incurring similar costs of just computing the angle directly.